# image, audio files stored on local computer are not getting displayed in my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a small peice of code, where the entire code is working fine but i think there is a unknown problem with file path given in the audio element . the given path is correct though.

```
// Initialize variables
let songIndex = 0;
let audioElement = new Audio('C://Users//ADMIN//Desktop//Web development_new//HTML_CSS//Project_spotify//data//PhotoGraph.mp3');
let masterplay = document.getElementById('masterplay');
let bar = document.getElementById('myBar')

// Play / Pause
masterplay.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (audioElement.paused || audioElement.currentTime <= 0) {
        audioElement.play();
        masterplay.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
        masterplay.classList.add('fa-pause-circle');
    }
    else {
        audioElement.pause();
        masterplay.classList.remove('fa-pause-circle');
        masterplay.classList.add('fa-circle-play');
    }
})

// Listen to events
bar.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
    console.log('timeupdate')
    // Updates Seekbar
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use URL or relative path of your mp3 music file instead of giving your file path.

Want I mean by relative path is that put your mp3 inside your project folder or where your index.html file exist.

Comment: In some other cases you might have made spelling mistakes in class names or id names.

Comment: Don't use file path use url or relative path

Comment: for example audio is the folder where your index.html file exist then your audio path should also exist inside the audio folder